# Spark SQL Java Unable to convert fromTuple to Row and Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create `Dataset<Row>` object from `JavaRDD<Tuple2<Row, Row>>` object.

I am following the below steps,

1. Convert `Java<Tuple2<Row,Row>>` to `JavaRDD<Row>`
2. Use `toDataset()` function of `sqlContext` with schema to convert into Dataset.

But, in first step I am not able to use `Row.fromTuple()` function like scala in code.
In second step, I am not able to convert using rowTag.

It's showing me below runtime error.

```
Error: java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method fromTuple(scala.Tuple2<org.apache.spark.sql.Row,org.apache.spark.sql.Row>)
  location: interface org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

I have tried to convert like below

```
ClassTag<Row> rowTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Row.class);

private Dataset<Row> joinResults(SparkSession session, RDD<Tuple2<Row, Row>> resultRDD) {
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Row, Row>> results = resultRDD.toJavaRDD();

    JavaRDD<Row> ds = results.map(new Function<Tuple2<Row, Row>, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Row call(Tuple2<Row, Row> rowRowTuple2) throws Exception {
            return Row.fromTuple(rowRowTuple2); // run time error
        }
    });
    
    return session.sqlContext().createDataset(ds, rowTag); //gives error
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am using [LuceneRDD Record Linkage](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd/wiki/Record-Linkage), which gives me RDD back so I don't have the option to do operations directly on Dataset. I don't want to create schema/encoder every time because that will limit the use of linkage function. I am using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.4.3 libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful -

### `Tuple2<Row, Row>` -> `Dataset<Row>`

```java
  StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add(new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()))
                .add(new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()));

        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Row, Row>> tuple2JavaRDD = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext())
                .parallelize(
                        Arrays.asList(Tuple2.apply(RowFactory.create(1), RowFactory.create("a")),
                                Tuple2.apply(RowFactory.create(2), RowFactory.create("b")))
                );
        JavaRDD<Row> rowJavaRDD1 = tuple2JavaRDD.map(t -> Row$.MODULE$.merge(
                toScalaSeq(Arrays.asList(t._1, t._2))
        ));
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD1, schema);
        df1.show(false);
        df1.printSchema();
        /**
         * +---+----+
         * |id |name|
         * +---+----+
         * |1  |a   |
         * |2  |b   |
         * +---+----+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
         *  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
         */
```

### `Tuple2<Integer, String>` -> `Dataset<Row>`

```java
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>> resultRDD = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext())
                .parallelize(Arrays.asList(Tuple2.apply(1, "a"), Tuple2.apply(2, "b")));
        JavaRDD<Row> rowJavaRDD = resultRDD.map(Row$.MODULE$::fromTuple);
        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD, schema);
        dataFrame.show(false);
        dataFrame.printSchema();
        /**
         * +---+----+
         * |id |name|
         * +---+----+
         * |1  |a   |
         * |2  |b   |
         * +---+----+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
         *  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
         */
```

Most of the spark apis work on scala seq, it's better to have below utility handy to convert java List -> scala Sequence

```java
 <T> Buffer<T> toScalaSeq(List<T> list) {
        return JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list);
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.!

Answer (score 2):

1. `.createDataset()` accepts `RDD<T>` not `JavaRDD<T>.` JavaRDD:
   You need to use `ds.rdd()`
2. You need to create and pass `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder`
3. Do not create a row of rows by `Row.fromTuple(rowRowTuple2)` (i.e. a row in which every element is a row). A single row should contain primitive types or nested structs ([example](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Row.html)).

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi. Can you also tell how we can use `Row.fromTuple` or `Row.merge` from java?